# What accounts for this word order?

Tags: word-order

I had translated the sentences,

> *John:* Tell Alex to get well soon.
> *Ben:* I will, I'm fine.

as,

> *John:* Sag Alex »Gute Besserung«.
> *Ben:* **Ich werde** tun, mir geht es gut.

and a native German speaker corrected it like this:

> > *John:* Sag Alex »Gute Besserung.«
> > *Ben:* **Werde ich**, mir geht es gut.

Why did she reverse the order of the verb and subject?

Comment: What is that *I'm fine* intended to transport? Is it simply, that Bens is not (yet) sick (then a whole new sentence would be more appropriate, but definitely something different from a mere comma) or that he is (gladly) willing to do that task?

Comment: @guidot: English note: "convey" and "transport" are total synonyms when talking about moving physical packages, but "convey" is the only one you can use with "meaning", even if the word "meaning" is left implicit.

Comment: If *Ben* is answering colloquially the future tense is inappropriate in German. A German speaker would use the present tense. Maybe "Mach ich". "Werde ich" sounds stilted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Ich werde tun* is incorrect because there is an object missing.

A way to correct this is to add a prounoun, for example a *das*:

> Das werde ich tun.

Now, in spoken German it is possible to omit a pronoun in first position. This gives us:

> Werde ich tun.

This is called an ellipsis and is valid German, although mostly restricted to colloquial usage.

Comment: "... to omit a pronoun in first position" -- and even the second part of the verb, including a possible dative object: *[das] werde ich **[(ihm) sagen/ausrichten; machen/tun]***

Comment: Note that you could also say "Ich werde das/es tun", but while technically applicable it's not very commonly used. Maybe this variant could also be pointed out in this answer?

Comment: English does have this, too. "Will do", colloq. for "I will do so" - a similar construction.