# Is this word order valid?

Tags: word-order, ellipsis

I found this among the subtitles to an episode of Die Chefin:

> Dann dehnen wir die Spurensuche eben aus. Kann man verlangen.

I do not understand how the word order could be correct in the second sentence. Is this an imperative or what?

If this is an ellipsis, that does not explain the wrong word order. Would it not have been more correct to create the ellipsis with

> Man kann verlangen?

Comment: Ellipsis tag added for better re-use and easier look-up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word order is not really correct as it is colloquial speech: one word is missing. The correct sentence should be:

> Dann dehnen wir die Spurensuche eben aus. **Das** kann man verlangen.

As pointed out by RHa in comments this is called „ellipsis“:

> The linguistic term for this is ellipsis. – RHa

And as RDBury showed this is also used in English sentences from time to time:

> It's a feature of most languages that you occasionally have to fill in missing elements to make a sentence grammatical. For example "What was Micheal doing? Rowing a boat." The second part "Rowing a boat" is not grammatical on it's own, but the subject "Micheal" and time frame were established in the previous sentence, so the missing elements, "Micheal was", are implied. Wikipedia has more details. – RDBury

Comment: It's a feature of most languages that you occasionally have to fill in missing elements to make a sentence grammatical. For example "What was Micheal doing? Rowing a boat." The second part "Rowing a boat" is not grammatical on it's own, but the subject "Micheal" and time frame were established in the previous sentence, so the missing elements, "Micheal was", are implied. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) has more details.

Comment: The linguistic term for this is *ellipsis*.

Comment: I would not call this incorrect. Also, omitting a leading *das* is colloquially very common.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60632/what-accounts-for-this-word-order/60633#60633

Comment: Related to [this meta discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/warum-werden-diskussionen-in-den-chat-verschoben-why-do-discussions-get-moved?cb=1) you might want to include the comments you mentioned explicitly.

Comment: didn't know that. thank you for the information @infinitezero

Comment: @infinitezero, personally, I usually do not mention usernames in answers in case that the users would want to change them at a later time.

Comment: @CarstenS: You can still link to the user account (where the link uses the user's permanent ID) and use a text like "a user". This way, you give credit without mentioning a user name that might change at a later time.